# Как описать указатель на форму в Visual C++?

Tags: .net, winforms, указатели, c++

Есть форма Form1.h, в которой имеется следующее описание:

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    ...
};
```

Как в другой форме или модуле описать указатель на эту форму?

`Form1^ MainForm;` - не работает, пишет ошибку:

> `error C2061: Синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "Form1".`

Comment: @Sergey041691, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: @Sergey041691 какой компилятор? это студия?
Выложите проект на файлообменник, щас проэксперментировал - все работает

Comment: Может быть все-таки Form ^ MainForm без единицы?

Comment: Наверняка вы просто забыли namespace. Или может, заказываете поле в неподходящем месте.

Comment: @ХэшКод, у меня одного нету кнопки "101010"? Вместо нее же {}?

Answer (score 1):

Могу ошибаться, но подключите в модуле, где хотите использовать файл Form1.h

```
#include "Form1.h"
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогает, это и так было прописано.